# Resume from suspend: missing icons, blank text and black areas in applications,

Tags: pantheon-files, google-chrome, suspend, thunderbird

Since about 1 week i got problems with resume from suspend.
Chrome has black areas and thunderbird has missing icons and no text.
When i restart these applications they are back to normal. This happens after every resume from suspend.

Pantheon-files has the same problem as Thunderbird.

How can i provide any log information about this special problem?

Screenshots: [Chrome and Thunderbird](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt8YH.jpg)

Comment: It seems to be an intel driver bug present in Linux kernel 4.4: https://askubuntu.com/questions/688306/text-missing-garbled-after-laptop-resumes-from-sleep-mode#711061